# Does the solana validator execute all the transactions in a block or a part of the block?

Tags: validator

Does the solana validator execute all the transactions in a block or a part of the block? If all the block will the confirm slow? Will it collect the whole block before execute the transactions in the block?

Answer (score 1):

A validator will execute all transactions in a block. Not all transactions are guaranteed to be successful.

Comment: so the failed transactions will be in a block too ?

Comment: That's right, all transactions are in the block, success or failure

Answer (score 0):

Hey answering your first question

1. Solana validators even include failed txns with they collected gas for and all the txns are executed as they validator is the chosen blockproducer.
2. nope that's the job
3. Could you elaborate on the 3rd question better?

Comment: the 3rd question : as we all know ,the leader will split the blocks into shreds to send to others, assuming that a block has multiple parts, if the second part is received, do we need to wait for the data from the first part to arrive before executing the second part?

Comment: So, a validator is expected to execute all the transactions in a block in time, is that means a validator shall has the hardware as well as the leader?